# Laravel: Saving a relationship when instanciating an Eloquent model rises this SQL error: "Integrity constraint violation"

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

## Summary

1. Context and Needs
2. Minimal, Testable and Executable sources (with instructions for testing)
3. Actual Results and Expected Results
4. What I've tried
5. The Question

---

## Context and Needs

The relationship between both Eloquent models `GalleryImage` and `GalleryGroup` is: `GalleryImage * <-> 1 GalleryGroup`. I want to save an instance of `GalleryGroup`, then of `GalleryImage`.

## Minimal, Testable and Executable sources

### Instructions to test

- I wanted to show you how to test my code in the case you really want to do it ;-) . However, I think you don't actually need to test. Indeed, the code is very simple. By reading it, if you know more than me Laravel, maybe you will find the problem and be able to bring me some help. I let you reading the following contents but I think you'll agree with me.
- Create the tables for `GalleryGroup` and `GalleryImage` (out of topic). The fields to create and the name of the tables are contained in the following sources.
- Copy/Paste the Eloquent models and the script that instanciates them and tries to save them in DB.
- Creates the routes of your choice to run the script and then, run the script (*ie.:* access the Web page or use a REST client)

### The Eloquent models

-- GalleryGroup.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class GalleryGroup extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primaryKey = 'group_id';
    private $name;
    
    public function images() {
        return $this->hasMany(GalleryImage::class);
    }
}
```

-- GalleryImage.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class GalleryImage extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primaryKey = 'image_id';     

    public function group() {
        return $this->hasOne(GalleryGroup::class, 'group_id', 'image_id');
    }
}
```

### Instanciations and concretization of the relationship

The Eloquent model `GalleryGroup` is instanciated and saved in db; then, the Eloquent model `GalleryImage` is instanciated and should be saved in db:

```
$img_group = new GalleryGroup();
$img_group->name = 'foobar';
$img_group->save();

$image = new GalleryImage();
var_dump($img_group->group_id);  // It exists and it's not empty
$image->group()->save($img_group);
$image->save();
```

## Actual Results and Expected Results

The last line is never executed because this error is raised at the line `$image->group()->save($img_group);`:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'group_id' cannot be null (SQL: update `gallery_groups` set `group_id` = ?, `gallery_groups`.`updated_at` = 2021-01-09 10:16:44 where `group_id` = 24) in file /var/www/html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 671

I don't understand why it tries to update the group entry, and I don't understand why `group_id` is `NULL` or empty, because `$img_group` actually has a non-empty `group_id` (*cf.:* the line `var_dump($img_group->group_id);`).

The actual results are: 1) the model `GalleryGroup` is correctly instanciated and correctly saved in db and 2) the model `GalleryImage` is correctly instanciated and not saved in db because of the above SQL error is raised.

The expected results are: 1) the model `GalleryGroup` is correctly instanciated and correctly saved in db and 2) the model `GalleryImage` is correctly instanciated and saved in db.

## What I've tried

I've tried to `var_dump` several times several variables but did not found any relevant information to help debugging this issue.

I've read and re-read the docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method and https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#primary-keys but did not found any relevant information to help debugging this issue.

## The Question

Why is this error raised and how to fix it?

Comment: you would need to save `$image` before you can associate it to `$img_group` otherwise there is no foreign key to set ... though your relationships seem off as they both can't be `hasX` ... one has to be a `belongsTo`, which is the real issue  ... so this is kinda backwards at the moment

Comment: In regards to the relationship described in the post, the foreign key to set is the ID of the group. So the group actually needs to be created first. Then the image will be created by indicating the ID of the group. This way, the relationship Images* <-> 1Group is correctly implemented. I don't understand why using `hasX` rather than `belongsTo` is problematic. I will read the docs again, part Relationships. T'y!

Comment: because 2 models can not be related to one another via hasOne or hasMany relationships, one of them would need to be a belongsTo .... Why? because one of them needs to have the foreign key on its table that references the other table which only belongsTo does, hasOne and hasMany mean the key is on the other table, so if both are hasOne or hasMany where are the foreign keys supposed to be that relate them?

Comment: Ah yes I see it. T'y very much. :)

Comment: Perhaps you should write a rapid answer telling me I've not used the belonging function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of these relationships needs to be a `belongsTo` as one of these tables has the foreign key on it that relates to the other table.  I would assume a GalleryImage belongs to a GalleryGroup:

```
GalleryGroup
    images
        hasMany GalleryImage

GalleryImage
    gallery
        belongsTo GalleryGroup
```

Once those are setup correctly you should be able to do this to save the relationship:

```
$img_group->images()->save($image);
```